# How to not get null values from User secret configs?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I want to use user secrets for KeyVault clientid etc. I call my configs from `program.cs` when I setup KeyVault. When I add the values in `appsettings.json` all works fine, but if I remove it and manage user secrets it's always say null when my `program.cs` is running.

And I have the correct values in the created `secret.json` and the attribute with a guid to it is also in my project file

I have also tried to add a key and value to the `secret.json` and tried to get it from a controller and it's also null.

So it seems like `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` in my `program.se` does not load my `secret.json` file.

And if I add `AssUserSecrets` to my `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` in `progam.cs` there is no difference same problem.

I'm using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` so it shall be used by default in asp .net core 2.2

```
dontnet user-secret list
```

Will also shows the values for me from my `secret.json` file so the value is there, the user-secret has been initialized.

```
dontnet user-secret init
```

Also, say it's already setup.

But still just null when calling my `secret.json` attributes

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                {
                    var config = builder.Build();
                    var vault = config["KeyVault:Vault"];
                    builder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{config["KeyVault:Vault"]}.vault.azure.net/", config["KeyVault:ClientId"], config["KeyVault:ClientSecret"]);

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault

because as soon I add that nuget it stops working.

UPDATE: More info. it seems like the latest Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault downgrade some of the configuration libs for me. And then it stops working.

Comment: I did not remove it... I saw it was gone so pressed it again. 

But It's not a direct answer to my question, so maybe someone else removed it? 

It seemed to be a conflict between the new version of .net core libs and the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault  so I'm now using the same versions Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault  use.

Answer (score 2):

I test in my site and it works fine, here is the steps you could refer to.

1.Right click on the project and select `Manage User Secrets`. It will open the secrets.json file in Visual Studio where you can add your secrets and it will add the   to the .csproj file.

[image]

2.Add what you may wish to add to your User Secrets. It includes two ways of writing a json object and a simple key/value pair. 
[image]

3.Mapping User Secrets to a model.

```
 public class KeyVault
 {
     public string Vault { get; set; }
     public string ClientId { get; set; }
     public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
 }
```

4.Adding the Configuration.
Install package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`

5.Bind the values. This is done in the Startup.cs file.
[image]

6.Using your mapped secrets

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly KeyVault _keyvault;
    // I’ve injected twilioAccountDetails into the constructor

    public HomeController(IOptions<KeyVault> keyvault)
    {
        // We want to know if twilioAccountDetails is null so we throw an exception if it is           
        _keyvault = keyvault.Value ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(keyvault));
    }
........
}
```

7.Call it in `Program.cs`.
[image]

For more details about how to use `User Secrets in a .NET Core Web App`, you could refer to this [article](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/05/user-secrets-in-a-net-core-web-app.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue when using `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` and discovered that it was because my host environment was not `Development`.

To resolve this I added the following section to my `launchSettings.json`:

```json
"environmentVariables": {
    "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}
```

See [related documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0):

> The following defaults are applied to the returned HostBuilder:
>
> - **load app IConfiguration from User Secrets when EnvironmentName is 'Development'** using the entry assembly

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing the following NuGet package:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets
```

Once I installed this, it worked perfectly.